# Why does Core only recognize a subset of whitespace characters?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

Char.is_whitespace is documented to return true only for ' ','\n','\t','\r'. Why doesn't it recognize '\f' and '\v' (form-feed and vertical tab)? POSIX and C both consider these to be whitespace, so it is very surprising that Core doesn't.

Comment: You should probably consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: you should ask the core mailing list. I agree though, it's probably an oversight on their part.